# PHP : add some html if file or image exit

Tags: php, html, postgresql, if-statement

Hi i want some help with my PHP if statement i have a database which holds the path to the images, and this is optional so some a are left null. i want to to print nothing if the field is null and print this if there is a path or any data `echo '<img src="..'.$row2[$i]['qpicture_dir'].'", style="float:">';`

this is my if statement

```
if (!empty($row2[$i]['qpicture_dir']) ){
  echo '<img src="..'.$row2[$i]['qpicture_dir'].'", style="float:">';
  }else{
  echo "";
  }
```

Comment: Ok, so...what's your question?

Comment: what is problem here? giving any error?

Comment: What do you put in that Column when the user does not enter an image?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: _Just guessing_, but `$row2[$i]['qpicture_dir']` is probably wrong. Can't tell without more of the surrounding code, but if `$row2` is a row you've fetched from a database, it probably doesn't have that many dimensions, and it should probably just be `$row2['qpicture_dir']`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(file_exists($row2[$i]['qpicture_dir'])){
   echo 'File exists';
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php